# How do I echo out particular wp_register_script or wp_enqueue_script version and id in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to echo out the version of a particular wp_register_script or wp_enqueue_script on the frontend.

Like Superfish JS registered via theme core files:

```
wp_register_script( 'superfish', GENESIS_JS_URL . "/menu/superfish{$this->suffix}.js", array( 'jquery', 'hoverIntent' ), '1.7.10', true );
wp_register_script( 'superfish-args', apply_filters( 'genesis_superfish_args_url', GENESIS_JS_URL . "/menu/superfish.args{$this->suffix}.js" ), array( 'superfish' ), PARENT_THEME_VERSION, true );
```

And, I want to get the version of these JS reflected on frontend via:

```
add_filter('the_content','addToEndOfPost');

function addToEndOfPost($content) {
    if (is_single()){
        return $content . '<p>Version of Superfish JS:</p>';
    }
    return $content;}
```

Even if I could get the separate script as a variable, I might be able to use a delimiter to separate out the version and id of these scripts. I'm trying WordPress development for the first time, so please help.

Answer (score 0):

To load a script with condition you need to use `wp_enqueue_scripts` action - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_custom_scripts');
function my_custom_scripts() { 
wp_register_script( 'superfish', GENESIS_JS_URL . "/menu/superfish{$this->suffix}.js", array( 'jquery', 'hoverIntent' ), '1.7.10', true );
wp_register_script( 'superfish-args', apply_filters( 'genesis_superfish_args_url', GENESIS_JS_URL . "/menu/superfish.args{$this->suffix}.js" ), array( 'superfish' ), PARENT_THEME_VERSION, true );

  //Add your condition and enqueue script
  if (is_single()){
    wp_enqueue_script('superfish');
  }
}
```